# Is there a Google Sheets script function that can download calendar events based on creation date versus event date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a Google Sheets script function that can download calendar events based on the date an event was created versus the date of the event itself? Advanced search parameters don't seem to include creation date. Any ideas?

Here's Google's literature:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)

Comment: Check [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Comment: Do you mean to retrieve all calendar events that are within a date range? Would [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) or the Apps Script documentation you shared suit your case scenario? This will retrieve a list of events under certain conditions like start end end time.